# When debugging a packacge in SQLDeveloper neither the Data nor the SmartData has any values. How can I fix?

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

Running SQLDeveloper 23.1.1 on an Oracle 19.19.0.0.0 DB when I try to debug a large package, and am at a breakpoint, when I click the Data tab I get;[image]

Which obviously shows no data. This has just started occurring, and it happens on smaller packages as well. I have tried it on two different computers running slightly different versions of SQLDeveloper with the same results.

I am using the following debug setup;
[image]

What do I need to do to continue troubleshooting this issue?

EDIT:
I tried the code supplied below and got similar results;

[image]

EDIT:

Interestingly when I mouse over variables it shows the current values. However the Data tab still shows nothing. This is a problem because I can't see into complex objects.

Comment: please confirm that program is COMPILED with DEBUG

Answer (score 0):

Compiled for DEBUG, my package, whilst debugging shows on the Smart Data Page -

[image]

And if I toggle to the Data page -

[image]

Wait, where are my package variables, X and Y?

Click to expand on the 2nd item there -

[image]

My code -

```
create or replace PACKAGE CUSTOMER_PKG AS
 x integer;
 y date;
PROCEDURE ADDCUSTOMER(
P_FIRST_NAME IN VARCHAR2 -- Customer's first name
,P_LAST_NAME IN VARCHAR2 -- Customer's last name
);
END CUSTOMER_PKG;
/

create or replace PACKAGE BODY CUSTOMER_PKG AS
PROCEDURE ADDCUSTOMER(
P_FIRST_NAME IN VARCHAR2 -- Customer's first name
,P_LAST_NAME IN VARCHAR2 -- Customer's last name
) AS
BEGIN
 X := 1;
 Y := sysdate + X;
END ADDCUSTOMER;
END CUSTOMER_PKG;
/
```

Comment: I tried your code, and I get the same results. There is nothing under Package Body Variables. One thing I noticed is under Details, PLSQL_DEBUG is FALSE. Is that true for you?

Comment: Also false for me, the more important thing is that you confirm the package spec and body are both COMPILED FOR DEBUG

Comment: I compiled for debug using the arrow next to the gears as well as right mouse on the package body and package. Is there a way to determine if a package is compiled for debug?

Comment: I believe I found the query to determine if something is compiled for debug.  select owner, object_name, DEBUGINFO from SYS.ALL_PROBE_OBJECTS where owner || '.' || object_name = 'DEVELOPE.CDS_PERSON_MATCHING_NEW' If DEBUGINFO = 'T' then it is compiled for debug.

Comment: SQLDev tells you if it's compiled for debug, it paints a green dot on the pkg in the tree, if you look close, it's a bug